# Arrow function should not return assignment in find array

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following line

```
    shareViewMetadata.sharedWith = [sharedWith.find((recipient) => (recipient.id = userId)) as UserView];
```

That gets the linting error:
Arrow function should not return assignment  no-return-assign
How could I fix it?

Comment: That code would always return the first element as long as the userId is truthy. Linter caught a bug since you were doing an assignment instead of a comparison.

Answer (score 2):

```
(recipient.id = userId)
```

should be

```
(recipient.id == userId)
```